# Using fpdf for generating A4 Prints

Tags: php, fpdf

I need to take bill print in 80 x 110 mm. am using `FPDF` format to create a PDFs. The size shown in the browser is correct that is 80 x 110, but when I take a print it comes under A4 size. I change to try A4 to letter, legal to set the size of 80 x 110.

Can anyone guide me further towards the resolution ??

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the [FPDF Constructor](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/fpdf.htm), as it has your answer. I'd also recommend the rest of the [FPDF API](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/index.php) for future reading. You can set a custom size for a PDF document as such:

```
$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm',array(80,110));
```